Using a local unpublished NPM package in the react native app
I have the following package mylibrary having a class and an interface exported.
src/Notification.ts
import {INotification} from 'INotification';

export class Notification implements INotification {
    private readonly _name: string;
    private _body?: any;

    public constructor(name: string, body?: any) {
        this._name = name;
        this._body = body;
    }

    public get name(): string { return this._name; }
    public get body(): any { return this._body;}
}

src/INotification
export interface INotification {
    readonly name: string;
    body?: any;
}

index.ts
export {Notification} from './src/Notification';
export type {INotification} from "./src/INotification";


Project using my library
I manually copied mylibrary into node_modules folder
package.json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.71.19",
  "mylibrary": "file:node_modules/mylibrary"
},

App.js
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {Notification} from 'mylibrary';

const App = () => {
  const n = new Notification('a', null);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{n.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;


Error
Render Error
Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.
I suspect that probably simulator is unable to find node_modules/mylibrary package from my computer because both emulator and desktop have different disk space allocations


I have used many packages as a local packages . You don't have need to add package name/path in package.json and folder of files in node modules . Add files in directly to your project src and access them.
